# If f ◦ g and g are one-to-one then f is one-to-one?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I was asked to prove or disprove the above question and "If there are functions g: A⟹B and f: B⟹C, if f◦g and f are one-to-one then g is one-to-one"

I think I have found a way to disprove it using the counterexample:
if f(x) = √x
and g(x) = x^2
then (f ◦ g)(x) = x, f and f◦g are injective, but g is not.

However, I am very stuck on the proof for the other statement:"If there are functions g: A⟹B and f: B⟹C, if f◦g and g are one-to-one then f is one-to-one"

Could someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: The statement in the title and the one in the body of your post are not the same. Which one is the one you would like to consider?

Comment: @EvanAad: it appears that there is an "if and only if" statement at play here, as both statements are used in the question body...

Comment: I would like some help with the question in the title as I'm finding that harder, but I'm glad someone could point out the flaw in my counterexample!

Comment: In your example, you have $(f\circ g)(x)=x$ for all $x\in A=[0;+\infty)$, a set on which $g$ is injective. If you take $A=\mathbb{R}$, then for all $x\in A$, you have $(f\circ g)(x)=|x|$, hence $f\circ g$ is not injective on $A$.

Answer (score 3):

The statement in the title is false. Take, for instance the functions $f:\{1,2\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, $g:\{1\}\rightarrow\{1, 2\}$ defined as follows.
$$
\begin{align}
f(1) &:= f(2) := 1 \\
g(1) &:= 1.
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is a singleton then $g:A\to B$ and $f\circ g:A\to B$ are automatically one-to-one.

Now let $B$ have more than one element, and let $f$ be constant. Then $f$ is not one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

Actually $f\circ g$ one-to-one alone ensures $g$ is one-to-one.

Proof by contrapositive: if $g$ is not one-to-one, $f\circ g$ can't be one-to-one.

For the question in the title,  $f\circ g$ and $g$ one-to-one don't ensure $f$ is.

As a counter-example, let$f(x)=x^2$, which is not one-to-one (it's an even function), $g$ be the canonical injection of $\mathbf R^+$ into $\mathbf R$. As $f\circ g$ is  just squaring on $\mathbf R^+$, it's one-to-one, yet $f$ isn't.